# Toolbar is going invisible on switching between fragments

Tags: android

I am developing an android app through `support design library` for `navigation drawer` and `toolbar`.I am switching to `fragment` on click of `navigation drawer` item such as `rootfragment`->`fragment1` ->`fragment2` ->`fragment3`. So far there is no problem.but when i want to come back on `rootFragment` such as `rootfragment`<-`fragment1` <- `fragment2` <- `fragment3`.On this toolbar is going invisible on each fragment. How to solve that problem.

**main activity xml file**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

<!--app:itemTextColor="@color/profile_name"-->
```

**appbar xml file is**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/containerView">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity code is:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


private TextView userName,userEmailId;
private ImageView profileImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,fragment,null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   //int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.home:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;


    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is inside of "containerView". Then you replace the "containerView" with the content of the fragments => the toolbar is not visible. To fix the problem move the Toobar outside of the "containerView".

Another approach is to have the "containerView" below the toolbar, like in the code below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you add the content on FrameLayout, below the Toolbar?

Comment: i am sure.Actualy i have hide action bar in some fragments and when i come back from hiding actionbar fragments then the problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace MainActivity XML with this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
<!--app:itemTextColor="@color/profile_name"-->
```

Comment: showing error  on drawer click ..IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Comment: Are you programmatically hide the action bar as like this this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Comment: Did you attach any navigation drawer in the Activity?

Comment: Yes u r right . i have hide action bar in some fragments bcoz i m using some custom action bar.And problem is also for this reason. what i need to do now?

Comment: While come back to the previous fragment, set getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: You can set the same from either Activity or Fragment.